# How can I expose a method with a parameter of type IHTMLDocument* to COM from C++?

Tags: c#, c++, com, com-interop

I have a C++ library (Win32) that fills some fields in a web page that I would like to use from .NET (an IE toolbar) but I can't figure out how to expose the method through COM. I already know I should add it to the interface in the .idl file like this:

```
interface IPlugin : IDispatch{
    #include <mshtml.h> 
    HRESULT FillFields(IHTMLDocument2* pDocument, BSTR value1, BSTR  value2);
};
```

but the #include of mshtml.h gives me the following errors:

```
error MIDL2003: redefinition : _LARGE_INTEGER
error MIDL2003: redefinition : _ULARGE_INTEGER
error MIDL2003: redefinition : INT
error MIDL2003: redefinition : Int64ShllMod32
```

Is there any way I can pass the IHTMLDocument object from C# to C++ and modify it's content in C++ or is COM supposed to be used only with types meant for Automation, like BSTR?

Thanks

Comment: Try moving the `#include` outside of your `interface`.

Comment: @spencercw I suppose I can only import other .idls outside of the interface because I get this error if I try to include the .h: `error MIDL2025: syntax error : expecting an interface name or DispatchInterfaceName or CoclassName or ModuleName or LibraryName or ContractName or a type specification near "pragmawarning( disable: 4049 ) File: mshtmlc.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `#import` to get the IDL definition of `IHTMLDocument2` into scope in MIDL.

The MIDL compiler will generate the `#include` for you. Explicit `#include` in MIDL files is useful only in a very narrow set of corner cases.

Comment: `import "mshtml.idl";` **after** `import "ocidl.idl";` is indeed the solution, thanks